# random Character and Skin Change buttons in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, flash, random

I have the code for both character random and skin buttons:

```
var HaurkaWS: Haurka_Wetsuit = new Haurka_Wetsuit();
var MinamiWS: Minami_Wetsuit = new Minami_Wetsuit();
var MinamiSWS: Minami_ShortWetsuit = new Minami_ShortWetsuit();
var KiraraWS: Kirara_Wetsuit = new Kirara_Wetsuit();
var TowaWS: Towa_Wetsuit = new Towa_Wetsuit();
var HaurkaSS: Haurka_Swimsuit = new Haurka_Swimsuit();
var MinamiSS: Minami_Swimsuit = new Minami_Swimsuit();
var KiraraSS: Kirara_Swimsuit = new Kirara_Swimsuit();
var KiraraBS: Kirara_Bikini = new Kirara_Bikini();
var TowaSS: Towa_Swimsuit = new Towa_Swimsuit();
```

For Character Button:

```
 var characterRandom: String;
 var characterRandomArray: Array = [HaurkaWS,MinamiWS,KiraraWS,TowaWS];
 var HaurkaSkin: Array = [HaurkaWS,HaurkaSS];
 var MinamiSkin: Array = [MinamiWS,MinamiSS,MinamiSWS];
 var KiraraSkin: Array = [KiraraWS,KiraraSS,KiraraBS];
 var TowaSkin: Array = [TowaWS,TowaSS];

character_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_pressCharacter);
function on_pressCharacter(e: MouseEvent): void {
    if(contains(DisplayObject(character)))
        {
            character = characterRandomArray.splice(int(Math.random() * characterRandomArray.length));
        }
}
```

For Skin button:

```
skin_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, on_pressSkin);
function on_pressSkin(e: MouseEvent): void {
    if(character == contains(DisplayObject(characterRandomArray[0])) && contains(DisplayObject(HaurkaSkin[0]))){
        var randomHaurkaSkin = HaurkaSkin.splice(int(Math.random() * HaurkaSkin[0].length));
    }
    else if(character == contains(DisplayObject(characterRandomArray[1])) && contains(DisplayObject(MinamiSkin[0])))
    {
        var randomMinamiSkin = MinamiSkin.splice(int(Math.random() * MinamiSkin[0].length));
    }
    else if(character == contains(DisplayObject(characterRandomArray[2])) && contains(DisplayObject(KiraraSkin[0])))
    {
        var randomKiaraSkin = KiraraSkin.splice(int(Math.random() * KiraraSkin[0].length));
    }
    else if(character == contains(DisplayObject(characterRandomArray[3])) && contains(DisplayObject(TowaSkin[0])))
    {
        var randomTowaSkin = TowaSkin.splice(int(Math.random() * TowaSkin[0].length));
    }
}
```

And then I have 2 errors:

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert []@26f82b72b21 to Haurka_Wetsuit.
    at WetWorldChallenge_fla::MainTimeline/on_pressCharacter()[WetWorldChallenge_fla.MainTimeline::frame491:148]

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/contains()
    at WetWorldChallenge_fla::MainTimeline/on_pressSkin()[WetWorldChallenge_fla.MainTimeline::frame491:157]
```

Actionscript for a extend MovieClip:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    
    public class Haurka_Wetsuit extends MovieClip {
        character = characterRandomArray[0];
        
        public function Haurka_Wetsuit() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }
}
```

Both have the same error: 1120: Access of undefined property character and characterRandomArray.

I was unable to change character or the skin, any ideas how to fix these?

Comment: The first or top error says you forcing (or coercing) something to become different to its type. Like forcing a stone to fold like paper, it won't work... You need to show how you define `var character`, I mean is it even the same data-type as `Haurka_Wetsuit`? Is this `character` a display object (MovieClip, Sprite, etc) and so **you want to add something inside it**? For that you can test as `character.addChild( characterRandomArray[ 0 ] );` instead of your current `character = characterRandomArray[0];`

Comment: PS: Thinking about it... Another way could be make your var like `var character: *;` then later test updating the var as `character = new Haurka_Wetsuit();` this makes "character" become a "Haurka_Wetsuit" object instead of just adding Haurka inside the character. Not sure which solution you want but test both ways of updating `character`...

Comment: Yes. I would like a character to change a different character or a skin. Then, there's an update for a TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Haurka_Wetsuit$ to flash.display.DisplayObject.

Comment: **(1)** _"There's an update for a TypeError: Error #1034:"_ If there is a new error you must tell us what you did (code?) to get this new error. **(2)** What is `Haurka_Wetsuit` anyways? Like **is it a display object (MovieClip, Sprite, etc)**, Yes or No? If Yes, then did you click the `Export for ActionScript` option (in the **Library**) for the Haurka_Wetsuit object? if Yes, then open that object's code (there is a button for editing the AS3, find it) and tell us what it says, should be something like `public class Haurka_Wetsuit extends MovieClip`...

Comment: Ok, I just typed in like you asked, and everything exported for Actionscript. Then, what is the next step?

Comment: _"I just typed in like you asked"_ I don't know what you **actually** typed. I gave you 3 suggestions, which one one did you use? If you change any code then [show it in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72727435/edit)... Your error is from `character = it cannot be this Object type`... To solve: You need to make character into a MovieClip if Haurka_Wetsuit is a MovieClip.

Comment: PS: `character` does not exist in your code...  I don't know why you think you can do `character = characterRandomArray... etc etc` without error about _"character is undefined or unknown"_. Did you **actually create** `character` as variable or you did something else to create `character`?

Comment: I'm talking about "public class Haurka_Wetsuit extends MovieClip"

Comment: The hardest thing in the world for you is to tells us **what TYPE of variable is character**. Your code is using `.splice` which **gives back an Array** (not some picture or animation). So tell me is this what you want : `character = a smaller spliced Array`?? If no, then stop using `splice` in your code. ... Anyways second thing, **if you can see** `Haurka_Wetsuit extends MovieClip` then you can try: first `var character : MovieClip;` to define it and then later update in functions as `character = characterRandomArray[ 0 ];` because `[0]` is the Haurka_Wetsuit in your Array (if not splice)

Comment: PS: _"everything exported for Actionscript. Then, what is the next step?"_ did you give the MovieClip of Haurka its own **Class Name** like `Haurka_Wetsuit` , if yes, then what do you see when you click the "pen" icon (second icon next to Class name box)... If it says `extends MovieClip` then it should work to use `character = characterRandomArray[0];` without error.

Comment: It's already typed in the class name, then what about the rest and the functions?

Comment: Then, if I have an error like: 1017: The definition of base class MovieClip was not found, 5000: The class 'Haurka_Wetsuit' must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type or 5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: character, Haurka_Wetsuit" What should I do?

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ **start a new fresh project for testing**....  You need to practice creating some graphic (try circle or square, just simple for testing...) then click it to select option "convert to movieclip" (so it shows in library). Click "export for actionscript,", click "export on frame 1", type whatever Class name like `myTestClass` and ok everything. Now in main code of your app you can define as `var character : MovieClip = new MovieClip(); var myHaurka : myTestClass = new myTestClass();` now other functions can try `addChild(character);` and `character.addChild(myHaurka)`...

Comment: If you cannot get one simple shape to show on the screen (or stage), then you need to follow tutorials about creating Class and MovieClips before you edit this current code in your question... It would have been fixed yesterday but you don't want to tell us what is `character` in your code (is it a drawing on stage with linkage name `character`? or some variable you created by code like `var character`) ???  This would help us to understand what data-type it is and also why the error says you cannot update character's type to become a type MovieClip (like data-type of Haurka).

Comment: 1. Character is an Instance Name and a symbol is a MovieClip. 2. var character: MovieClip = new MovieClip();

Comment: Keep it as `var character: MovieClip;` (no "=new" part) then in function **on_pressCharacter** you can try `character = new Haurka_Wetsuit();`... To work make sure that **Haurka_Wetsuit** is showing as a **MovieClip** in the Library. If there is an object on stage called character (with instance name), delete the instance name and convert character to MovieClip (with **linkage** name in Class Name box) because it must come from only Library to be added on stage (using `addChild` command). You access character by its _linkage_ name from Library, not by _instance name_ from Properties. Practice

Comment: Yes, it is working. But I want to random the character when I click the character button from an array